# Javascript add values to object dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamically-generated

Let's supose i have something like this:

```
$scope.playersData =   [{
    "label": obj.data[0].player,
    "color": colors[0],
    "data": obj.data[0].value
}, {
    "label": obj.data[1].player,
    "color": colors[1],
    "data": obj.data[1].value
}];
```

This works if i have always only 2 items in obj.data.

Now, if i want to add values dynamically in a For Loop, how do i do it?

I tried something like this, not working:

```
var temparray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    temparray[i] = {"label": obj.data[i].player,"color": colors[i],"data": obj.data[i].value};
}
```

Comment: You can always use `.push()`, but even as it stands, that should be good enough. What exactly isn't working here? BTW, shouldn't you check for `i < obj.data.length` instead?

Comment: Please consider adding a JSfiddle to show your current error.

Comment: is it `data.length` or `obj.data.length` ?

Comment: It's obj.data.length, my mistake... Please give the answer so i can vote. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
var temparray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    var item = {"label": obj.data[i].player,"color": colors[i],"data": obj.data[i].value};
    temparray.push(item);  //. <---added
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one mistake: replace from `data.length` to `obj.data.length`.

Also, you can use `push` for adding element to array.

```
var temparray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) { 
    temparray.push({"label": obj.data[i].player,"color": colors[i],"data": obj.data[i].value});
}
```